# Node.js - Session doesn't persist through res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, redis, express

I'm (almost) successfully using Node.js with Express and Redis to handle sessions.

The problem I'm having is that the session is not kept when I use `res.redirect()`.

Here is how I can see it :

```
req.session.username = username.toString();
console.log(req.session);
res.redirect('/home');
```

The console.log() prints :

```
{ lastAccess: 1322579131762,
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     httpOnly: true,
     _expires: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 15:06:31 GMT,
     originalMaxAge: 60000 },
  username: 'admin' }
```

Now, here is the following code :

```
app.get('/home', [app.requireLogin], function(req, res, next) {
// Not showing the rest as it's not even getting there
// Instead, here is what's interesting
app.requireLogin = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
```

This console.log() prints out this :

```
{ lastAccess: 1322579131775,
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     httpOnly: true,
     _expires: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 15:06:31 GMT,
     originalMaxAge: 60000 } }
```

Clearly, the 'username' object has disappeared. The session has not kept it, and just rebuilt a new one.

How can I solve this? Don't hesitate if you need any information.

Here is the code where I set the session management :

```
app.configure(function() {
  // Defines the view folder and engine used.
  this.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  this.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  // Allow parsing form data
  this.use(express.bodyParser());

  // Allow parsing cookies from request headers
  this.use(express.cookieParser());
  // Session management
  this.use(express.session({
    // Private crypting key
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new RedisStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 60000
    }
  }));
  this.use(app.router);
});
```

Here is the whole project (I mean, parts of it), on gist : https://gist.github.com/c8ed0f2cc858942c4c3b (ignore the properties of the rendered views)

Comment: Can you also paste the code where you are including the Redis session store? There is a timeout option there, maybe you accidentally set it too low.

Comment: Added :) It's set at 60 seconds, and I clearly don't use 60 seconds to write the credentials...

Comment: I assume this is a small project, I think it better to post it somewhere (gist, pastie) and give a link. I bet the error is somehow in a code that you're not pasting. (just a guess)

Comment: Added the gist link at the end

Comment: @Florian I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Comment: Similar case to my that answer and it works on my machine
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902329/16445411 .

Comment: Similar case of my that answer and it works on my machine
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902329/16445411

Comment: Similar case to my that answer and it works on my machine
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902329/16445411

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution. The problem is that the time in `maxAge` was added to the current date. So, in the browser side, the cookie was set to expire at the GMT time shown.

The problem was the following : I use a virtual machine to test node.js, and, you know... sometimes, you suspend your machine.

Well, what happened is that the machine's time was two days late. So, whenever the cookie was set on the server side, the client side thought the cookie was already expired, since my host machine was not two days late.

Another stupid outcome.

Comment: Hey, I have a similar problem. Could you please help me out here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512910/express-session-is-not-storing-data-when-using-res-redirect

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with different browsers ? Are you keeping the same session id between page redirects ?

You could add `req.session.cookie.expires = false;` before redirecting...

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty solid, but is there a reason you're using client.end()? It forcibly closes the redis connection and is not clean. I don't think you need it at all:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/74

I am not sure about the underlying architecture for connect-redis, but I'm wondering if calling client.end is what's resetting your sessions. What happens if you take those out?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I thought it'd be cleaner. It doesn't solve the problem though, but I'm +1'ing you :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem in that I was setting something on the session that was not persisting outside the `app.get()` it was set in.

My problem turned out to be that I was **not** doing a `res.redirect()` at the end of my `app.get()`.  Looks like I was setting something on a request object and then allowing it to get garbage collected.

I added a `res.redirect( '/nextmethod' )` and the data persists just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to save that session in some way, this might work.

```
req.session.regenerate(function(){
    req.session.username = username.toString();
    res.redirect('/home');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything, unfortunately. By the way, what's the point of this regenerate function?

Comment: If you are going to modify data stored in a persistent database, it's only logical that you will need to *save* it before you can use it in other parts of your system.  I am surprised that req.session.username variable persists *without* saving anything... maybe it is done automatically as a feature